# Limitations in passing a huge list of ID array in parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering if there are any issues/consequences when passing a huge chunk of id array via parameter. There is a browser url limitation, but what if I send the request via `ajax` `http` `get`? Are there still any possible limitation problems like for example the following?

```
@users = User.all
my_method_path(:user_ids => @users.pluck(:id))
```

Comment: You could always change it to POST if the limitation is a problem. There you have "unlimited" space. But what are you trying to achieve here, because I've never run into such a situation?

Comment: Let's say I have a list of users that needs to be processed for something, I have already made some queries to sort them out but now I need to pass them via ajax to for another process. Currently it's working but my main concern is that if this gets too big I might run into some limitation issues

Comment: Use a Ajax POST / PATCH instead. You won't run into any issues with size, and it's best practice when sending data other than a single ID.

Answer (score 0):

There is no thumb rule made for the maximum URL size of HTTP Get Request as per RFC 2616 (Hypertext Transfer Protocol — HTTP/1.1 – Section 3.2.1).

Limits are imposed by **various browsers** and respective servers.

Just use plain POST request with JSON body.